# Bash script ffmpeg pic to video not working but does in command line

Tags: video, ffmpeg

This works in command line for a sequence of jpg to convert to a video.

```
cat *.jpg  | ffmpeg -f image2pipe -framerate 5 -i - -s 1280x720  ./HD720_out.mp4
```

but doesn't work (except for first jpg) in a executable script temp.sh  containing:

```
eval  cat "$1"  | ffmpeg -f image2pipe -framerate 5 -i - -s 1280x720  "./HD720_out.mp4"
```

e.g. `./temp.sh *.jpg`   gives only the first file to video, not the sequence.  What am I doing wrong?  The command line works perfectly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simplified: `$1` gets expanded to the first commandline argument of a script.

But before your script interprets the shell running temp.sh will first expand the asterisk <kbd>*</kbd> in `./temp.sh *.jpg`, effectively resulting a in a commandline:

```
./temp.sh first.jpg second.jpg third.jpg 
            \
             \_  $1
```

You have two options to get around this. The first (and preferred):

```
cat "$@" | ...
```

will just use all command line paramters, not  only the first one. You don't need `eval` for this one and shouldn't use it.

The second (where `eval` comes into play):

```
eval cat "$1"  |
```

while calling the script with quoted parameters to avoid expansion:

```
 ./temp.sh '*.jpg'
```

Comment: @Sven Thanks for amending my short explanation as you did. I was on mobile and a bit terse.